# Socket_connect using proxy socks5?

Tags: php

How can I connect and hide my ip using socks5? I thought of using cURL, but it works only with http(s). How can I hide ip with send socket data or connect? Is it possible?

```
socket_connect($this->sock, $address, $port);
```

Answer (score 0):

CURL allows to use socks5:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'YOUR_PROXY_SERVER_HERE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
```

Comment: Socket - tcp connection.